# Are Hamilton's equations reversible?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, reversibility, time-reversal-symmetry

Say I define a [time dependent vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dependent_vector_field) $\Psi(t):\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ as [reversible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641766/why-is-this-system-reversible-what-does-this-mean) (also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559268/why-is-this-system-reversible-nonlinear-dynamics)) if, for $f(x,y)=(x,-y)$, we have:

$$ f\circ \Psi \circ f =\Psi(-t)=\Psi^{-1}(t).$$

Just to clarify $\Psi:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$. Now let $\Psi$ be some [Hamiltonian dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) $\Psi=(q,p)$, where:

$$ \frac{d q}{dt}=\nabla_p H (q,p), \ \ \ ~q(0)=x, $$
$$ \frac{d p}{dt}=-\nabla_q H (q,p), \ \ \ ~p(0)=y, $$
where $H(q,p)=H(q,-p)$. Is it obvious that $\Psi$ is reversible? Can I use [Reversibility of Hamiltonian dynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/528020/) somehow?

(Note the 2nd equality $\Psi(-t)=\Psi^{-t}(t)$ follows since $(q,p)$ is a flow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics) )

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282607/226902

Comment: Solved: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/698059/why-inverse-flow-of-separable-hamiltonian-with-even-kinetic-energy-can-be-writte?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

1. A dynamical equation system with dynamical variables $z$ is called *reversible* if it is invariant under the combination $(t\to -t, z\to I(z))$ where $I$ is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))$^1$, cf. Ref. 1.
2. *Main example:* Any [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) Hamiltonian $H(q,p)=H(q,-p)$ that is even in momenta describes a reversible system. Here the involution is $I(q,p)=(q,-p)$.
3. Concerning OP's title question, it is possible to find non-reversible non-autonomous Hamiltonian systems. Think e.g. on a Hamiltonian of the form $H(q,p,t)=f(t)q+g(t)p$ for 2 appropriate functions $f,g$.
4. More interestingly, Ref. 1 claims [e.g. around eq. (1.29)] that there exist non-reversible autonomous Hamiltonian systems.

References:

1. J.A.G. Roberts & G.R.W. Quispel, *Chaos and time-reversal symmetry. Order and chaos in reversible dynamical systems.* [Phys. Rep.
   216 (1992) 63](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(92)90163-T).

---

$^1$ More generally in a geometric language: If $M$ denotes the manifold of dynamical variables (sans time $t$), then the map $I:\Gamma(TM)\to \Gamma(TM)$ is a (possibly time-dependent, not necessarily integrable) mixed tensor field, such that it is pointwise an involution $\forall z\in M: I_z^2={\bf 1}_{TM}$. This is often called an *almost product structure* in the literature.

Comment: For a system to be reversible, the involution in question need not be $\vec{p} \to -\vec{p}$, right?  I'm thinking of (for example) a particle in a magnetic field, which is not even in $\vec{p}$ but might have an involution of $\vec{p} \to - \vec{p} + 2 q \vec{A}$ or something like that.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Right.